# Snippet Dark Background is scrollable when disabling responsiveness

Tags: support, bug

If you disable responsiveness on Stack Overflow at the bottom of the footer and then reduce the width of the screen so you can scroll horizontally, the dark background of the snippet moves to the right and left. In the approximate it looks like this:

[image: Here]

Comment: Considering that the non-responsive site [is deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), and it has been confirmed that no work will be done on future bugs, nothing is going to change here. The responsive site is what is being pushed now. From the linked post: *"We’ll be adding [[meta-tag:status-declined]] on existing and future mobile-only bug reports and pointing to this post since those views are getting unshipped."*

Comment: @Larnu mhmm okay